# WPF: How to write efficiently a storyboard for multiple controls with the same animation and different event handler for `completed`?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, storyboard

I have a navigation bar which contains some buttons. When the user clicks on one of them, the same storyboard is triggered, but a different event handler is called. Here is the code for each button:

```
<Button x:Name="<!-- Button's name -->">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="FrameTest"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    To="0"
                    Duration="0:0:1" 
                    Completed="<!-- Different event handler -->" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    Messages
</Button>
```

There are lots of buttons and this is **VERY** repetitive. Is there a way to write it in a more elegant way?

Comment: Oh that's simple; shove the storyboard in question in a resource dictionary, give it an x:Key="NameGoesHere" and then use it as a resource over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you're trying to achieve, it's impossible to know for sure what would work best for you. But if I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to create a single declaration of a `Storyboard` and/or of one or more `Animation` objects, reuse that object on multiple `Button` objects, but still be able to have different event handling for the `Completed` event.

Unfortunately, the `Completed` event isn't routed so, as far as I know, you do have to subscribe to it directly. But this still leaves room for at least a couple of different approaches that I think should work.

IMHO, the simplest is to actually have just one event handler, but have it be able to handle the completion for whichever target was used. Note that the sender of the `Completed` event in the example you provided is the `AnimationClock` for the timeline. In code-behind, you can retrieve the timeline (e.g. your `DoubleAnimation` object) from that, and then can retrieve the target information from the animation via the `Storyboard`'s static methods. For example:

```
string targetName = Storyboard.GetTargetName(((AnimationClock)sender).Timeline);
```

In your example above, the `targetName` variable would receive the value `"FrameTest"`. In this way, a single event handler can respond appropriate according to which object was actually being animated.

Note that if you are going to declare the `Storyboard` object as a resource and then reuse it on multiple elements, you'll want to include `x:Shared="false"` in its declaration, to ensure that each element that uses it gets its own copy of the `Storyboard` object.

An alternative technique common in WPF and often useful for extending the way objects act is attached properties, and the related concept of "behaviors" (something that is supported by the Expression extensions, but which you can also implement yourself if you like). These allow you to, as with the `Storyboard.TargetName` attached property, maintain custom information and actions for WPF objects.

You could, for example, create an attached property that allows you to define an `ICommand` object to execute, an `Action` delegate to invoke, or a routed event to raise when the `Completed` event fires. Your attached property would perform the appropriate configuration depending on your implementation when the property is set.

The advantage of something like that is that you would be able to use the XAML to customize the behavior for each target element (i.e. the `Button` objects), rather than hard-coding information in the shared event handler.

**Addendum:**

Based on your comment and your reference to the other question you posted, it seems you have the following additional criteria:

- There is a single object being animated, while you have multiple buttons all affecting this object.
- The object is a `Frame` object, and you want to be able to update the `Content` property of this object when the animation has completed.
- You want to be able to declare the `Storyboard` object once, and be able to have each button initiate the animation, and then individually define what should happen when the animation completes.
  This third point is problematic, because the `Storyboard` and its animations are not even aware of the `Button` object that initiates them, and so having the animation's `Completed` event handler vary its behavior based on the `Button` instance that started it is not possible without additional effort.

Based on that understanding, below is a simple code example that shows *one possible way* the above could be achieved.

*(Aside: I emphasize "one possible way", because one of the consequences of WPF's great flexibility is that often there is a maddeningly large number of different ways to accomplish the same goal. Those of us who are not experts in WPF then find that we may or may not know the* best *way to do something, because we found* some *way to do it and stopped there. :) )*

Anyway…

First, the entire example relies on a custom attached property, shown here (this can be done using the "behaviors" idiom too — a special type of attached property — but IMHO that would just unnecessarily complicate the example, even if it is a nice way to do it):

```
class AttachStoryboard
{
    public RoutedEvent Trigger { get; set; }
    public Storyboard Storyboard { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Completed;

    public void RaiseCompleted()
    {
        EventHandler handler = Completed;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

static class StoryboardHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachStoryboardProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AttachStoryboard", typeof(AttachStoryboard), typeof(StoryboardHelper), new PropertyMetadata(_OnAttachStoryboardChanged));

    private static void _OnAttachStoryboardChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement target = (FrameworkElement)d;
        AttachStoryboard attachStoryboard = (AttachStoryboard)e.NewValue;

        if (attachStoryboard != null)
        {
            BeginStoryboard beginStoryboard = new BeginStoryboard { Storyboard = attachStoryboard.Storyboard };
            EventTrigger trigger = new EventTrigger(attachStoryboard.Trigger);

            trigger.Actions.Add(beginStoryboard);
            attachStoryboard.Storyboard.Completed += (sender, e1) => attachStoryboard.RaiseCompleted();

            target.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        }
    }

    public static void SetAttachStoryboard(FrameworkElement target, AttachStoryboard value)
    {
        target.SetValue(AttachStoryboardProperty, value);
    }

    public static AttachStoryboard GetAttachStoryboard(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        return (AttachStoryboard)target.GetValue(AttachStoryboardProperty);
    }
}
```

Next we need to declare some event handlers in the code-behind. In this case, one per button, but of course you could generalize this further by adding more context to the attached property that would allow an event handler to know the source.

**Note:** because there is *not* the context to allow a single event handler to handle the animation completion for each button, it's important that each button get its own private copy of the `Storyboard`, by using `x:Shared="false"` (see XAML below). So one motivation for generalizing this further would be that if you did, you could get away with a single `Storyboard` resource object, and not having to set `x:Shared="false"`.

The entire `MainWindow.cs` of the example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Storyboard storyboard2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        storyboard2 = (Storyboard)FindResource("storyboard2");
    }

    private void button1_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frame1.Content = "Button #1 Content";
        storyboard2.Begin(frame1);
    }

    private void button2_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frame1.Content = "Button #2 Content";
        storyboard2.Begin(frame1);
    }

    private void button3_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frame1.Content = "Button #3 Content";
        storyboard2.Begin(frame1);
    }
}
```

For each button, it updates the `Content` property of the `Frame` object, and then starts the "fade-in" animation to reveal the updated content.

Finally, there is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO36386403SharedStoryboard.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO36386403SharedStoryboard"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
    <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard1" x:Shared="false">
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="frame1"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                       To="0" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard2">
      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="frame1"
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                       To="1" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
    </Storyboard>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button #1">
      <l:StoryboardHelper.AttachStoryboard>
        <l:AttachStoryboard Trigger="Button.PreviewMouseDown"
                            Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}"
                            Completed="button1_Completed"/>
      </l:StoryboardHelper.AttachStoryboard>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button #2">
      <l:StoryboardHelper.AttachStoryboard>
        <l:AttachStoryboard Trigger="Button.PreviewMouseDown"
                            Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}"
                            Completed="button2_Completed"/>
      </l:StoryboardHelper.AttachStoryboard>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button #3">
      <l:StoryboardHelper.AttachStoryboard>
        <l:AttachStoryboard Trigger="Button.PreviewMouseDown"
                            Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}"
                            Completed="button3_Completed"/>
      </l:StoryboardHelper.AttachStoryboard>
    </Button>
    <Frame x:Name="frame1" Content="Initial Content"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The above simply declares the two `Storyboard` resources being used and initializes the attached property for each button appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. You understand my problem perfectly. Could you please demonstrate how your suggestions will look like? Also, in your first solution, the "targetName" is always the frame, but I need to know the button who fired the animation, and not the target of that animation. What do I miss here? Thank you very much, Peter!

Comment: I also posted another question with a more complete and detailed explanation of the general situation I am in. It's not excactly the same question so I posted a new one,  Please see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402710/wpf-how-to-create-a-navigation-system-with-a-shared-completed-event-for-the-p

Comment: Please see my edit, with an example of how using an attached property might look.

Comment: This is GENIUS. I thank you so much for this detailed, great great answer. I would like to suggest that as the answer of the week if I could...