# In WPF, How to create a storyboard with a `Completed` event handler which recognize the button that triggered the storyboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to build a navigation system for my application. The guiding principle that I followed was to carry out everything about animation in XAML so that I could maintain a complete separation between logic and design. Here is how I have tried to build it.

I want to create a `Frame`, which will be a container of `Page`s. The navigation system contains buttons, and clicking one of the buttons changes the `Content` of The `Frame` to another `Page`:

```
FrameName.Content = new PageName();
```

Visually, I want the navigation to be animated: the `Frame` is faded out, then the `Page` changes, and finally, the `Frame` fades back in.

The first step was to create a fade-out animation for the `Frame` when the user presses the buttons. I duplicated the following code for each button:

```
<Button x:Name="<!-- Button name -->">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="FrameName"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
    <!-- Button content -->
</Button>
```

Then, when the animation ends, I want to call an event handler which replaces the `Content` of the `Frame` to the new page. So, I added  a `Completed` event to the `Double Animation`:

```
<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.TargetName="FrameName"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
    To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"
    Completed="ButtonName_Completed" />
```

The event handler looks like this:

```
private void ButtonName_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrameName.Content = new PageName();
}
```

The next step will be to fade in the `Frame` when its content changes. Unfortunately, I realized that there was no built-in routed event for that. After searching and asking here in stackoverflow, I received the following code, which I do not completely understand, but ultimately works. It creates a custom routed event for changes in the `Frame`'s content:

```
public class MyFrame : Frame
{
    public static readonly RoutedEvent ContentChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ContentChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MyFrame));

    public event RoutedEventHandler ContentChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(ContentChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnContentChanged(object oldContent, object newContent)
    {
        base.OnContentChanged(oldContent, newContent);
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ContentChangedEvent, this));
    }
}
```

The frame is called `MyFrame` and it actually inherits from `Frame` and implements a routed event `ContentChangedEvent`. The XAML for `MyFrame`:

```
<local:MyFrame x:Name="FrameName" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden">
    <local:MyFrame.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MyFrame.ContentChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="FrameName"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        To="1"
                        Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </local:MyFrame.Triggers>
</local:MyFrame>
```

So far everything is working fine. My problem is this: I have to write the fade out animation for each button separately since each implements a different event handler when the animation ends, and because it's the same animation every time, the code is unbearably repetitive.

The solution I have tried is to create one event handler for all the buttons to refer to, and in it, I decide, based on the pressed button, which page should be present in the `Frame`. In this way, I can write the storyboard once, and then begin the animation from the `Buttons`'s triggers. Later on, I would also like to create a template for the `Button`s, containing all the relevant triggers so the code will be very short and elegant, I think.

For that, I need to find out which `Button` the user pressed,  inside the shared event handler (for the `Completed` event). The problem is that the `sender` is of type `AnimationClock` (because the `sender` is a `Storyboard`, I think....) and not `Button`. I can not think of a way to find out which button the user pressed.

I did try to find out by checking which `Control` is in focus, but it is not very elegant. While it works, it has an annoying bug. When the user clicks the button, and during the animation presses <kbd>tab</kbd>, the focus changes and the application stops (I think because the focus changes from the `Button` to a control of a different type):

```
/* Every button begins a storyboard, and when it ends, this method is called */
private void DoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // How to find out which control fired the animation?
    // Tried `Button btn = sender as Button;`
    // But `sender` is of type`AnimationClock`, not `Button`

    Button btn = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as Button;
}
```

In summary, is there a way to find out which button the user pressed through the shared `Completed` event handler? If not, is there a better way to build this navigation? Maybe I should write this navigation system in a completely different way?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**
Could anyone please suggest an accurate title to this question because It's a bit hard to me to summarize... Thanks...

Comment: I am very new to WPF, so it is more than likely that this is a stupid question. However, I would be grateful for a serious answer. Also, sorry for my English if it is not very good. :) I have tried my best to explain my problem, hope you could help me.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - Thanks. Could you please help me? :)

Comment: Please note that the accepted answer has been deleted, due to its poor quality. Please consider in the future not encouraging such poor answers by refraining from up-voting or accepting them.

Comment: As for the question above, this seems like a variation on the previously-asked question, which I answered to your satisfaction. If that's correct, please consider editing that other question so it includes the relevant details you provided here, and then just delete this one. If that's not correct, please edit the above question to make it clear how it's different from the other question and what you still need help with. Be sure to include a good [mcve] in that case.